# "invalid memory address" when calling Go from Python

Tags: python, go

I'm trying to extend the code in [Calling Go Functions from Other Languages](https://dev.to/vladimirvivien/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages). I'd like see how a function returning an error can be handled. See the code below, I get `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` when running the Python code. Any ideas on how to fix this?

*gmath.go*

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

import "C"

//export Div
func Div(x, y float64) (float64, error) {
    fmt.Printf("Div called: x=%f, y=%f\n", x, y)
    if y == 0 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("ZeroDivisionError")
    }
    return x / y, nil
}

func main() {}
```

*gmath.py*

```py
import ctypes


class GoInterface(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('t', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('v', ctypes.c_void_p),
    ]


class DivRet(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('result', ctypes.c_float),
        ('error', GoInterface),
    ]


lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./gmath.so')
lib.Div.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]
lib.Div.restype = DivRet

r = lib.Div(1.2, 2.3)
```

*Example run*

```
$ make
go build -o gmath.so -buildmode=c-shared gmath.go
$ python gmath.py
Div called: x=1.200000, y=2.300000
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x17 pc=0x7fbe5fda928d]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main._cgoexpwrap_448ea9090bef_Div.func1(0xc42003cea8)
    command-line-arguments/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:46 +0x42
main._cgoexpwrap_448ea9090bef_Div(0x3ff3333333333333, 0x4002666666666666, 0x3fe0b21642c8590b, 0x0, 0x0)
    command-line-arguments/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:48 +0xaa
[1]    29009 abort (core dumped)  python gmath.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the error part of result is the initial issue. If I change error to a string and return the (float64, *C.char), it works.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/xOqrJjS7-xE